# Nokia Lumia 620 suddenly cannot receive or send mms messages

Tags: lumia, settings, messaging

I have had a nokia lumia for about 2 weeks, and suddenly my mms messages aren't coming in, or sending. I am connected to Wi-Fi, and my data is turned on. It just suddenly stopped yesterday

Comment: Do you have good mobile phone network coverage?

Comment: Check Settings > Access Point and make sure all the details are correct for the network the phone is on.

Comment: I have tried in all different levels of coverage.

Comment: Have you checked the APN settings are correct for your network?

Comment: Who's your carrier?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am now going through the same thing. Picture mms would send just fine for a couple weeks, now they won't! I'm getting ticked!